# Возникает ошибка your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''users' WHERE 'login' = '@uL' AND 'password' = '@uP'' at line 1"

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

```
private void lodButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String loginUser = login.Text;
            String passUser = password.Text;

            DB db = new DB();

            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'login' = '@uL' AND 'password' = '@uP'", db.getConnection());

            command.Parameters.Add("@uL", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = loginUser;
            command.Parameters.Add("@uP", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = passUser;

            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            adapter.Fill(table);

            if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
                MessageBox.Show("Yes");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("no");
        }
```

Comment: вы везде ставите кавычки для названий полей неправильные. Либо используйте правильные (бэк тики) либо уберите совсем. `SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = '@uL' AND password = '@uP'

Comment: выделяет и говорит что ошибка  adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            adapter.Fill(table);

Comment: А вы думаете, что у вас одна ошибка? ) Их у вас две и я вам только одну убрал. Вторая - это убрать кавычки вокруг @параметр - они тоже похоже не нужны, их убирает параметризатор запросов.

Comment: убрал их все равно выдает ошибку на
            adapter.Fill(table);

Comment: Гм. В Dapper точно эти кавычки не нужны были, а на чистом ADO я так давно писал, что возможно там это иначе.

Comment: Не устану повторять: хранить в базе пароли в открытом виде - низкий, аморальный поступок.

Comment: извините,но я только учусь а препод еще не все нам обьяснил

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = @uL AND password = @uP"`

Comment: [Полистал примеры en so](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+command.Parameters.Add) - всё правильно, без кавычек должно быть, разве что рекомендуют использовать не .Add а .AddWithValue - но допустим... Я думаю, что у вас а) теперь с синтаксисом SQL теперь всё правильно б) с ADO тоже правильно, а вот почему адаптер не может заполнить -- это какой-то отдельный вопрос и отдельная ошибка. Возможно, нельзя звёздочку ставить, надо указывать точно поля в нужном порядке. Не работал с такими адаптерами.

Comment: я понял про какие кавычки,не сразу заметил поменял но теперь выделяются они

Comment: сейчас попробую

Comment: или так ``"SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = @uL AND `password` = @uP"``

Comment: @AK Я слышал, что как раз наоборот про `AddWithValue`. Но там все сложно и зарыто в выборе правильной перегрузки метода `Add`.

Comment: спасибо,все заработало

Comment: видимо с синтаксисом у меня еще есть проблемы

Comment: Если заработало - отпишите правильный/итоговый вариант кода в поле "Ответ", вдруг кому-то ещё пригодится.

Comment: @AK [AddWithValue is Evil](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/),  [AddWithValue is evil!](http://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html), [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: @aepot Любопытно, спасибо за ссылки.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void lodButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String loginUser = login.Text;
            String passUser = password.Text;

            DB db = new DB();

            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = @uL AND `password` = @uP", db.getConnection());

            command.Parameters.Add("@uL", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = loginUser;
            command.Parameters.Add("@uP", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = passUser;

            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            adapter.Fill(table);

            if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
                MessageBox.Show("Yes");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("no");
        }
```

Comment: Меня всегда удивляло, зачем заполняют DataTable, когда нужно проверить, существует ли запись (в данном случае user) в таблице. Используйте один из запросов [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1676551/5045688). Выкиньте `DataTable` и `MySqlDataAdapter`. Используйте метод `ExecuteScalar()`.